# Template Conflict for Palindrome Algorithm on String (Array)

Tags: generics, d, palindrome, range, dmd

After having viewed the excellent [Three Unlikely Successful Features of D by Andrei Alexandrescu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BRTX86DfOY) I tested the palindrome algorithms given there as follows

```
import std.exception;

bool isPalindrome(T)(T[] a)
{
  for (; a.length > 1; a = a[1 .. $-1]) {
    if (a[0] != a[$-1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool isPalindrome(Range)(Range r)
{
  for (; !r.empty; r.popFront(), r.popBack()) {
    if (a.front != a.back) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

unittest {
  enforce(isPalindrome("dallassallad"));
}
```

The array version works fine on strings but when I add the range-version to the same compilation unit DMD (2.062) complains:

```
palindrome.d(31): Error: template palindrome.isPalindrome matches
more than one template declaration,
palindrome.d(10):isPalindrome(T)(T[] a) and
palindrome.d(20):isPalindrome(Range)(Range r)
```

My guess is to limit the use of the range to not include the array case. How do I do that?

I also tested to remove the array version but then I get the error

```
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(22): Error: no property 'empty' for type 'string'
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(22): Error: undefined identifier 'popFront'
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(22): Error: undefined identifier 'popBack'
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(23): Error: undefined identifier a, did you mean variable r?
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(23): Error: undefined identifier a, did you mean variable r?
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(27): Warning: statement is not reachable
/home/per/Work/cognia/palindrome.d(31): Error: template instance palindrome.isPalindrome!(string) error instantiating
```

I seems the range-version doesn't work for arrays which I find strange.

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a template constraint to the second template like so:

```
bool isPalindrome(Range)(Range r)
    if (!isArray!Range)
```

You will need to import `std.traits` for the `isArray` template.

If you want to use only the second template you will have to import `std.array` which uses `UFCS` (Uniform Function Call Syntax) to enable arrays to have the `front`, `popFront`, `empty`, etc, functionality.

UFCS basically means that:

```
int[] x;
int f = x.front;
```

Is translated into:

```
int f = front(x);
```

`front` and others are defined for arrays in `std.array`, which enables you to use arrays as if they are ranges. You can use the same technique for your own types. You can define the range functions such as `front` inside a struct/class, or you can define them externally as functions which take your struct/class as their first paramater.

See the docs for [std.range](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html) for more info.

Comment: Is it, performance-wise, motivated to keep the array-specialized  `isPalindrome` alongside the generic one or is it just for educational purpose?

Comment: You could use `std.datetime` from `std.datetime` to do some timings and compare. Down at the assembly level with all optimizations and -inline perhaps the two functions will end up being the same. The function that specializes on the array uses slicing, whereas the generic one uses helper functions. However the generic one is more correct since it will properly work with string ranges (or string arrays), as the `front` call will properly decode a code point, whereas the specialized array version would end up comparing code units.

Answer (score 5):

Also please note there's an embarrassing bug in the generic version as it might try to reduce an empty range. A corrected version is:

```
bool isPalindrome(Range)(Range r)
{
    while (!r.empty) {
        if (a.front != a.back) {
          return false;
        }
        r.popFront();
        if (r.empty) {
            return true;
        }
        r.popBack();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: also the `scope(exit)` and `scope(failue)` where backwards in your slides (so cleanup happened before rollback)